# Prevent text overlaying slideshow images

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a MCVE of a slideshow I cobbled together from examples I found.

The issue I'm trying to solve is to prevent the fourth block of text from overlaying the image (or being overlaid by the image).

The second block of text is after the image that is between the first and second blocks of text, whereas the slideshow container doesn't affect the position of the 4th text block - it's as if the slideshow container wasn't there.  I'm guessing it's something to do with the `position` in the css.

The place where it will be used is inside a wordpress-like CMS that wraps the content with a menu, sidebar. footer, etc. that makes the page responsive, so I want to preserve that behaviour.

How do I make the fourth text block honor the space taken by the slideshow image?

```js
var current = 0 ; 
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide") ; 
setInterval 
  ( function() 
    { 
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length ; i++) 
      { 
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0 ; 
      } 
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1 ;  
    }, 2000) ;
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Title 1</h1>

<p>text before image.</p>

<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy36m99oqw61xuf/image1.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />

<h2>Title 2</h2>

<p>Text after image.</p>

<h2>Title 3</h1>

<p>text before slide.</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">
 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy36m99oqw61xuf/image1.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/miek22fw9ghqgw2/image2.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6ehi40kdlmli63/image3.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>
</div>

<h2>Title 4</h2>

<p>Text after slide.  We want this title and text block to start after the image container so that this text is not on top of the image or obscured by it.</p>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: what's your desired outcome?

Comment: Did you tried to give the 2nd paragraph a class name and give it a width and make it  less so it don't overlap the slider?

Comment: I've added some more to the example to make it clearer. @TheUnKnown I don't follow what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a height on your .slideshow-container{}

```js
var current = 0 ; 
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide") ; 
setInterval 
  ( function() 
    { 
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length ; i++) 
      { 
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0 ; 
      } 
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1 ;  
    }, 2000) ;
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Title 1</h1>

<p>text before slide.</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">
 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy36m99oqw61xuf/image1.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/miek22fw9ghqgw2/image2.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6ehi40kdlmli63/image3.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>
</div>

<h2>Title 2</h2>

<p>Text after slide.  We want this title and text block to start after the image container so that this text is not on top of the image or obscured by it.</p>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks.  Can you please explain how your `clearfix` class works?

Comment: @rossmcm haha sorry thats not meant to be there. I didnt see that the slide show was absolutely positioned at first. Ill remove it.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```js
var current = 0 ; 
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide") ; 
setInterval 
  ( function() 
    { 
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length ; i++) 
      { 
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0 ; 
      } 
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1 ;  
    }, 2000) ;
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  }
  
 #slideMid
 
 {margin-left:500px;
 width:150px;
 height;50px;
 
 }
```

```html
<h2>Title 1</h1>

<p>text before slide.</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">
 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy36m99oqw61xuf/image1.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/miek22fw9ghqgw2/image2.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6ehi40kdlmli63/image3.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>
</div>
<div id="slideMid">
<h2>Title 2</h2>

<p>Text after slide.  We want this title and text block to start after the image container so that this text is not on top of the image or obscured by it.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setheight(slide){
  var height = slide.offsetHeight;
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container")[0];
  container.style.height = height;
  container.setAttribute("style","height: " + height + "px");
}
document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container")[0].setAttribute("style","height: 225px");

var current = 0 ; 
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide") ; 
setInterval 
  ( function() 
    { 
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length ; i++) 
      { 
      slides[i].style.opacity = 0 ;
      setheight(slides[i]);
      } 
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1 ;  
    }, 2000) ;
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  }

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Title 1</h1>

<p>text before slide.</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">
 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img id="slide1" class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/zy36m99oqw61xuf/image1.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/miek22fw9ghqgw2/image2.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6ehi40kdlmli63/image3.jpg?raw=1" width="128" />
 </div>
</div>

<h2>Title 2</h2>

<p>Text after slide.  We want this title and text block to start after the image container so that this text is not on top of the image or obscured by it.</p>
```

With js you can do it maybe for variable heights, just need a start height with this example. Just an example with js, maybe useful maybe not :) Hope it helps